# ImageResizer - Firefox background color

Tags: imageresizer

I am using the image resizer tool (which is amazing), and I have a question regarding the bgcolor parameter and FireFox.  On Chrome, everything works great... my image is padded to the dimensions I want as you can see here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FK8pD.png

However, with the same image processing in FireFox, I get black bars on the top and bottom of the padded image:

http://img196.imageshack.us/img196/425/xply.png

My querystring is this:
&w=189&h=230&mode=pad&anchor=middlecenter&bgcolor=white

NOTE: full link isn't posted because it is on a staging server and not yet public.

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, but confused as to why it doesn't work in FireFox...

Thanks!

EDIT: Per request of ImageResizer author:
Full path after host: JGAImages/5053488_o/8c15484f-2988-4bb4-a7e5-cca1787d403b/jpg?v=2&w=189&h=230&mode=pad&anchor=middlecenter&bgcolor=white

Version I'm using: 3.3.3 - March, 2013

Comment: What version of ImageResizer are you using? Could you share the path (I.E, after the hostname)? Also, can you share the original image?

Comment: Here's the path after the host name: /JGAImages/5053488_o/8c15484f-2988-4bb4-a7e5-cca1787d403b/jpg?v=2&w=189&h=230&mode=pad&anchor=middlecenter&bgcolor=white 

And the version is: 3.3.3, Mar 2013

Comment: Try `&bgcolor=fff` and `format=jpg`. Do either of these help?

Comment: No... I tried both at the same time, and one or the other and still the padding background color is black.

Comment: So I might have found something interesting... I have this querystring like above '&w=189&h=230&mode=pad&bgcolor=fff&anchor=middlecenter' ... and I was looking at your basic doc page and you have the querystring setup with ";" instead of "&"... so I changed mine around until I got it to not produce a black padding at all on the top or bottom with this querystring: '&w=189&h=230;mode=pad&bgcolor=fff&anchor=middlecenter' ... just a simple change after the width and height.

Comment: If I add a ";" to all the parameters AFTER the height one, it works as well in all browsers, however if I add the ";" for the width and height, it breaks and just produces a un-resized image.

Comment: Are you using a question mark to begin the query string? Omitting the question mark (or accidentally URL-encoding it) would cause this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Your query string isn't reaching the server; ImageResizer doesn't see the `bgcolor=white` command

Typically this happens when ASP.NET (or a JS library) 'helpfully' URL-encodes your `?`, thus causing ASP.NET to discard the query string.

It can also happen if you simply forget the `?`, or if a CDN or caching layer is stripping the query string.

Comment: Yup.  I was an idiot and missed something during the function with the settings.  Fixed now. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

This should perhaps be a comment, but I don't have enough reputation to do that, but is the black background part of the Firefox background that it uses when showing any image? I don't use Chrome, but does that add a white background? Maybe both Firefox and Chrome are seeing the padded white as a transparent colour?

Comment: Hmm... that makes sense because the extra padding in Chrome appears as white, while in FireFox, it is black.  But it's werid because the control has a bgcolor parameter and I'm explicitly passing white.  Is this a limitation for FireFox?